# multiple alarm clock in javascript using dynamic generated input elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a web page which will allow to set multiple alarms using dynamic element creation property of javascript but I'm not able to get the values of these multiple elements and create a alert on that time.
This is my code so far

```
<div id="TextBoxContainer">
     <!--Textboxes will be added here -->
</div>
<br />
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="add" onclick="AddTextBox();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
        var room = 0;
        var i = 0;
        function GetDynamicTextBox(){
            return '<div>Alarm ' + room +':</div><input type="number"style="text-align:center;margin:auto;padding:0px;width:200px;" min="0" max="23" placeholder="hour" id="a'+room+'" /><input type="number" min="0" max="59" placeholder="minute" style="text-align:center; padding:0px; margin:auto; width:200px;" id="b'+room+'" /><input type="date" style="margin:auto;text-align:center; width:200px; padding:10px"><input type="button" value ="Set" onclick = "AddAlarm('+room+');" /> <input type="button" value ="Remove" onclick = "RemoveTextBox(this)" />';
        }
        function AddTextBox() {
            var div = document.createElement('DIV');
            div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
            document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
        }

        function RemoveTextBox(div) {
            document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
        }

        function RecreateDynamicTextboxes() {
                var html = "";
                html += "<div>" + GetDynamicTextBox() + "</div>";
                document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").innerHTML = html;
                room++;
        }
        window.onload = RecreateDynamicTextboxes;

        function AddAlarm(values){
            var hour = document.getElementById('');
            var minute = document.getElementById('');
            var date = document.getElementById('');
        }
</script>
```

Comment: thats great! but whats your problem???

Comment: how to receive the multiple inputs and then create a alert on that time

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the ID attribute on the date input and you were collecting the input elements in AddAlarm instead of their values.

EDIT: To check the alarms you have to store them and check every minute, if the current date matches one of the alarms. I added a short implementation there.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="TextBoxContainer">
     <!--Textboxes will be added here -->
</div>
<br />
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="add" onclick="AddTextBox();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
        var alarms = {};
        var room = 0;
        var i = 0;
        
        setInterval(function() {
          var current = new Date();
          for (var nr in alarms) {
             var alarm = alarms[nr];
             console.log("checking alarm " + nr + " (" + alarm + ")");
             if(current.getHours() == alarm.getHours() 
              && current.getMinutes() == alarm.getMinutes()) { // also check for day, month and year
                alert("ALERT\n"+alarm);
             } else{
                console.log('Alarm ' + nr + '('+alarm+') not matching current date ' + current);
             }
          }
        }, 60000);
        
        function GetDynamicTextBox(){
            return '<div>Alarm ' + room +':</div><input type="number"style="text-align:center;margin:auto;padding:0px;width:200px;" min="0" max="23" placeholder="hour" id="a'+room+'" /><input type="number" min="0" max="59" placeholder="minute" style="text-align:center; padding:0px; margin:auto; width:200px;" id="b'+room+'" /><input type="date" style="margin:auto;text-align:center; width:200px; padding:10px" id="c'+room+'"><input type="button" value ="Set" onclick = "AddAlarm('+room+');" /> <input type="button" value ="Remove" onclick = "RemoveTextBox(this)" />';
        }
        function AddTextBox() {
            var div = document.createElement('DIV');
            div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
            document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
        }

        function RemoveTextBox(div) {
            document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
        }

        function RecreateDynamicTextboxes() {
                var html = "";
                html += "<div>" + GetDynamicTextBox() + "</div>";
                document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").innerHTML = html;
                room++;
        }
        window.onload = RecreateDynamicTextboxes;

        function AddAlarm(values){
            var hour = $('#a'+values).val();
            var minute = $('#b'+values).val();
            var date = $('#c'+values).val();
            console.log(hour + ':' + minute + ' on ' + date);
            var dateObj = new Date(date);
            dateObj.setMinutes(minute);
            dateObj.setHours(hour);
            console.log(dateObj);
            alarms[values] = dateObj;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: but how will a alert be generated on these multiple input ?

Comment: @SachinSharma I updated the answer and added an alarm check.

Comment: hey @Eytibi thanks for trying, I have done everything but I am not able to solve the delete and update problem, when I am deleting the div, I don't know how to delete it's data from the array.

Comment: If you have the index, it should not be a problem: Using my example code, it should work like this: `delete alarms[index];`

Answer (score 0):

So far I'm able to generate a alert when the values match the system time but I don't know how to delete the array value when an element is deleted. I am not able to do it. This is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var snd = new Audio("clock.mp3"); // buffers automatically when created
        // Get
        if (localStorage.getItem("test")) {
            data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"));
        } else {
            // No data, start with an empty array
            data = [];
        }

        var today = new Date();
        var d = today.getDay();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        //since page reloads then we will just check it first for the data
        function check() {
        //current system values
        console.log("inside check");
        //if time found in the array the create a alert and delete that array object
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var today = new Date();
            var d = today.getDay();
            var h = today.getHours();
            var m = today.getMinutes();

            if (data[i].hours == h && data[i].minutes == m && data[i].dates == d ) {
                data.splice(i,1);
                localStorage["test"] = JSON.stringify(data);
                snd.play();
                alert("Wake Up Man ! Alarm is over ");
                }
            }
            if((data.length)>0)
            {
                setTimeout(check, 1000);
            }

        }
        //we do not want to run the loop everytime so we will use day to check
        for(var i =0 ; i< data.length; i++)
        {
            if((data[i].dates == d) && (data[i].hours >= h) && (data[i].minutes >= m) )
            {
                check();
            }
        }

        console.log(data);


        var room = 1;
        //var data = [];
        var i = 0;
        function GetDynamicTextBox(){

            var date = new Date();
            var h = date.getHours();
            var m = date.getMinutes();
            var d = date.getDay();

            return '<div>Alarm ' + room +':</div><input type="number" style="text-align:center;margin:auto;padding:0px;width:200px;" min="0" max="23" value ='+h+' placeholder="hour" id="a'+room+'" /> <input type="number" min="0" max="59" placeholder="minute" style="text-align:center; padding:0px; margin:auto; width:200px;" id="b'+room+'" value ='+m+' /> <select id="c'+room+'" style="margin:auto; width:150px; padding:10px; color: black" required> <option value="1">Monday</option> <option value="2">Tuesday</option> <option value="3">Wednesday</option> <option value="4">Thursday</option> <option value="5">Friday</option> <option value="6">Saturday</option> <option value="0">Sunday</option> </select> <input type="button" value ="Set" onclick = "AddAlarm('+room+');" /> <input type="button" value ="Remove" onclick = "RemoveTextBox(this)" />';
        }
        function AddTextBox() {
            room++;
            var div = document.createElement('DIV');
            div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
            document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
        }

        function RemoveTextBox(div) {
            document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
        }

        function RecreateDynamicTextboxes() {
                var html = "";
                html += "<div>" + GetDynamicTextBox() + "</div>";
                document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").innerHTML = html;
        }
        window.onload = RecreateDynamicTextboxes;

        function AddAlarm(values){
            var hour = $('#a'+values).val();
            var minute = $('#b'+values).val();
            var date = $('#c'+values).val();

            //get the current time and date
            var today = new Date();

            //current system values
            var d = today.getDay();
            var h = today.getHours();
            var m = today.getMinutes();

            //first check that whether a same date present in the array or not then push it
            var found = -1;
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].hours == hour && data[i].minutes == minute && data[i].dates == date ) {
                    found = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //if value does not present then push it into the array
            if(found == -1)
            {
                data.push({hours: hour, minutes: minute, dates: date});
                //storing it into localstorage
                localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(data));
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Same value Exists");
            }

            //console.log(data);

            function check() {
                //current system values
                //console.log("inside check");
                //if time found in the array the create a alert and delete that array object
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var today = new Date();
                    var d = today.getDay();
                    var h = today.getHours();
                    var m = today.getMinutes();

                    if (data[i].hours == h && data[i].minutes == m && data[i].dates == d ) {
                        data.splice(i,1);
                        snd.play();
                        alert("Wake Up Man ! Alarm is over ");
                    }
                }
                if((data.length)>0)
                {
                    setTimeout(check, 1000);
                }

            }
            //we do not want to run the loop everytime so we will use day to check
            for(var i =0 ; i< data.length; i++)
            {
                if((data[i].dates == d) && (data[i].hours >= h) && (data[i].minutes >= m))
                {
                    check();
                }
            }
        }



        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a notification whenever a given time or state is reached, I think you are looking for `setInterval` (see [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)).

This method allows you to take action at a regular interval and it tries to honor that interval the best it can. It opens to a common mistake if your action can take longer than that interval duration so be careful not using a too short interval. In such case, actions can overlap and weird behavior will occur. You *do not* want that to happen so don't be too greedy when using that.

For an alarm project, I would recommend an interval of one second.

Example (not tested):

**JavaScript**

```
var alarmDate = new Date();
alarmDate.setHours(7);
alarmDate.setMinutes(15);
// set day, month, year, etc.

var ONE_SECOND = 1000; // miliseconds

var alarmClock = setInterval(function() {
    var currentDate = new Date();

    if (currentDate.getHours() == alarmDate.getHours() &&
             currentDate.getMinutes() == alarmDate.getMinutes() 
      /* compare other fields at your convenience */ ) {
        alert('Alarm triggered at ' + currentDate);
        // better use something better than alert for that?

}, ONE_SECOND);
```

To add dynamic alarms, you could put them into an array then have your `setInterval` iterate over it.

In the long run you will probably get sick of `alert` and feel the need to use something that doesn't break the flow of your application. There are *a lot* of possibilities, one being the use of lightboxes that could stack over each other. That way you would be able to miss an alarm and still be notified by the next one.

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: I've used the setTimeout(), it's seems to be working fine thanks , but I am having one more issue that when i delete a dynamic element the value is still in the object array , how can I delete the value too

Comment: @SachinSharma You need to have a relation between the element and the value in the object array. Maybe you can set a name to your element and have a name field included in the object array?